# Flexslider: how to show thumbnails of slides before clicking?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to replicate the effect on http://residentialbylandsecurities.com/ On their slider, if you hover over the arrows, it shows a thumbnail of the upcoming slide. I've installed the same slider (FlexSlider), but this is a customization. My example site is [here](https://saifee-signs.squarespace.com/) (unfinished).

Their script is running in [this file](http://residentialbylandsecurities.com/wp-content/themes/ls-residential/js/scripts.js), but that's so long and sprawling and doing so much more than I need that I want to just write my own function.

My pseudocode:
1. Mainpulate the next/prev controls to add div.thumbnail to each
2. Locate the slides before and after the currently active slide, and save them in variables (prevSlide, nextSlide)
3. Get the data-thumb attributes from these slide img elements, and save each in variables (prevThumbData and nextThumbData)
4. Locate .next div.thumbnail and .prev div.thumbnail
5. Apply prevThumbData and nextThumbData as CSS background-images to their respective elements.
6. CSS: When hover over the arrow elements, slide in div.thumbnail

I don't need to use the other site's function at all unless it's simpler, I just need to accomplish the above. I've already set up my IMG elements to have the data-thumb attribute, but haven't figured out how to modify the slider to include div.thumbnail.

EDIT: I think I figured out the second and third steps in the procedure:

**2. Locate the slides before and after the currently active slide, and save them in variables (prevSlide, nextSlide)**

```
function flexThumbs() { 
var slider = $('.flexSlider div ul')
var slides = new Array(slider.children());
var images = slide.find('img'); 
var currentSlide = $("li.flex-active-slide");
// find next and previous slides
var totalSlides = slider.slides.length;
    var nextSlide = slider.currentSlide + 1;
    if (nextSlide >= totalSlides)
        nextSlide = 0;
    var prevSlide = slider.currentSlide - 1;
    if (prevSlide < 0)
        prevSlide = totalSlides - 1;
```

**3. Get the data-thumb attributes from these slide img elements, and save each in variables (prevThumbData and nextThumbData)**

```
var prevThumbData = $(prevSlide > "img").attr("data-thumb");
var nextThumbData = $(nextSlide > "img").attr("data-thumb");
}
```

Comment: they are actually only moving a background image via css hover from `right:88px` to `right:0` .  no need for javascript

Comment: That's not the tricky part. The tricky part is how they got that background image there. When you slide through, the thumbnail of the next slide is showing. That thumbnail is loaded dynamically through JS since the previous/next slides are always changing. My slider has the slide in and out, you can see, but I can't figure out how to add those thumbnails.

Comment: your right. I was only considering what was making the images show.  the image itself is being loaded dynamically for each slide.

Comment: Am I retrieving that information correctly in the code example above? Once I've done so, how do I apply that to my thumbnail arrows?

Comment: Actually, I haven't even figured out yet how to manipulate the default arrows for flexSlider. The script injects them dynamically and I can't figure out how to modify that output to add an element (for the thumbnail preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is in their `scripts.js`file.

First in the section where they call on `.flexslider()` they're passing a `after:` callback. Which is just one of the default callback options in flexslider.

after callback:

```
            after: function (slider) {
                if (!isTouch) {
                    mainSlider.setThumbs(slider);
                    flexsliderCopy.fadeIn(300); // Fade text back in
                } else {
                    //mainSlider.removeBulk(slider.currentSlide);
                }
            }
```

So we see they're calling a `.setThumbs()` method. A quick ctrl + f reveals:

```
            mainSlider.setThumbs = function (slider) {
                var totalSlides = slider.slides.length;
                var nextSlide = slider.currentSlide + 1;
                if (nextSlide >= totalSlides)
                    nextSlide = 0;
                var prevSlide = slider.currentSlide - 1;
                if (prevSlide < 0)
                    prevSlide = totalSlides - 1;

                prevThumb.find('div').css({
                    backgroundImage: 'url(' + slider.slides.eq(prevSlide).attr('data-thumb') + ')'
                });
                nextThumb.find('div').css({
                    backgroundImage: 'url(' + slider.slides.eq(nextSlide).attr('data-thumb') + ')'
                });

                prevThumb.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
                nextThumb.animate({
                    opacity: 1
                });
            };
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thank you! Looks like they're also calling some prevThumb and nextThumb variables.

Comment: @authorandrew, yeah in their `script.js` at line 164-165 they define both prevThumb and nextThumb

Comment: Quick question: do I have to use the mainSlider object (I think it's an object. If all I'm taking from their code is this one function, I don't need it, right? The console is passing this: _ReferenceError: mainSlider is not defined_

EDIT: I've removed it, but I can't figure out how to manipulate the arrow controls on flexSlider. The HTML is in the code, it's not something that I can add manually. How can I manipulate it to add flex-thumb-wrap?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you could probably just rename it as a stand alone function. They have their script.js set up to do fancy OOP stuff, you probably don't need to mess with it.

Comment: I've added the code into the options, but I can't figure out how or where to manipulate the arrow controls. Any ideas?

Comment: The jQuery variables for prevThumb and next Thumb reference this code:
`<div class="flex-thumb-wrap"><div class="flex-prev-thumb"></div></div>`
I've tried to add this into my slider code, but no dice. I think I need to add it directly next to the arrow controls, so that it can slide in on hover, however, I can't access that code as flexslider seems to inject it dynamically.

Comment: The actual reference is this: `var prevThumb = $('<div class="flex-thumb-wrap"><div class="flex-prev-thumb"></div></div>');` This isn't actually calling that code, it's generating it, correct?

Comment: I can't figure this out.